# How can I stop my animation from running when stoprun = 1?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, replit

I have tried th1.join but that didn't work and I don't know what else to try.

Also, I need it to be a single function

Here is my code:

https://repl.it/@JamesGordon1/JuicyScentedCrypto
(sorry too long to post)

Comment: always put code as text, not link.

Comment: you may need to use `queue` to send information to thread

Answer (score 1):

On Linux it works for me only if I add two things

1. I have to set `stoprun = 1` after loop

   ```
   c = InKey()
   while not c == 27:
       c = InKey()

   stoprun = 1 # set after loop
   ```
2. I have to use `print()` in thread - probably it needs `\n` (or it simply needs this IO function to change running thread)

   ```
   if stoprun == 1: # True
       print()  # have to send `\n`
       return
   ```

I don't know why it is needed but threads in Python doesn't run at the same time - one thread is bloking other thereads - and maybe these elements stops one thread and let to run other thread.

---

Of course it needs also `global stoprun` inside `stop()`

---

```
from threading import Thread

import time
import sys
import os

# --- classes ---

class _GetCh:
    def __init__(self):
      try:
        self.impl = _GetChWindows()
      except ImportError:
        try:
          self.impl = _GetChMacCarbon()
        except ImportError:
          self.impl = _GetChUnix()
    def __call__(self):
      return self.impl()

class _GetChWindows:
    def __init__(self):
      import msvcrt
    def __call__(self):
      import msvcrt
      if msvcrt.kbhit():
        while msvcrt.kbhit():
          ch = msvcrt.getch()
        while ch in b'\x00\xe0':
          msvcrt.getch()
          ch = msvcrt.getch()
        return ord( ch.decode() )
      else:
        return -1

class _GetChMacCarbon:
    def __init__(self):
      import Carbon
      Carbon.Evt
    def __call__(self):
      import Carbon
      if Carbon.Evt.EventAvail(0x0008)[0]==0:
        return ""
      else:
        (what,msg,when,where,mod)=Carbon.Evt.GetNextEvent(0x0008)[1]
        return msg & 0x000000FF

class _GetChUnix:
    def __init__(self):
      import tty, sys, termios
    def __call__(self):
      import sys, tty, termios
      fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
      old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
      try:
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
      finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
      return ord(ch)

InKey = _GetCh()

# --- main ---

stoprun = 0 # False

def load_animation():
  load_str = "starting your console application "
  ls_len = len(load_str) 
  animation = "|/-\\"
  anicount = 0      
  i = 0
  while True:
    time.sleep(0.075) 
    load_str_list = list(load_str) 
    x = ord(load_str_list[i]) 
    y = 0                           
    if x != 32 and x != 46:          
      if x>90: 
        y = x-32
      else: 
        y = x + 32
      load_str_list[i]= chr(y) 
    res =''          
    for j in range(ls_len): 
      res = res + load_str_list[j] 
    sys.stdout.write("\r"+res + animation[anicount]) 
    sys.stdout.flush() 
    load_str = res 
    anicount = (anicount + 1)% 4
    i =(i + 1)% ls_len
    if stoprun == 1: # True
        print()  # have to send `\n`
        return

def stop():
  global stoprun

  print ("Press Esc to exit")

  c = InKey()
  while not c == 27:
    c = InKey()

  stoprun = 1 # have to be after loop

  return

th1 = Thread(target=load_animation)
th1.start()
stop()
#th1.join()
```

Comment: this kinda works but know it writes the next frame after every print

Comment: do you use Linux? If you use other system then maybe it works in different way and it has different problem.

Comment: i run it on repl.it

Comment: but i have a chromebook

Comment: `repl.it` may have to catch your key by browser and send it to server so it may work even different then `Linux`, `Window` or `Mac`

Answer (score 0):

In `stop` you write:

```
  while not c == 27:
    c = InKey()
    stoprun = 1
  return
```

The `stoprun = 1` will create a new local name `stoprun` instead of modifying the global variable because you never marked `stoprun` global. Do this:

```
def stop():
    global stoprun
    ... # your code
```